# How to read last line of CSV file into a list that I can manipulate (python)

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv

I wrote a small function that will return the last row of a csv file.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to store that row into a list or array to use after the function has completed.

```
import os
import csv
hello = []
def getLastFile(filename):
    distance = 1024
    with open(filename,'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        reader.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        if reader.tell() < distance:
            reader.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
            lines = reader.readlines()
            lastline = lines[-1]
        else:
            reader.seek(-1 * distance, os.SEEK_END)
            lines = reader.readlines()
            lastline = lines[-1]
    return lastline
```

I have tried defining an empty list at the top, and appending lastline to that list, but I found that that was wrong.  Right now the function returns a csv row, ex: 'a','b','c', how can I make the output of my function save this into a global list or array that I can then use? Thank you!

Comment: What does "I found that that was wrong" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the result of a function to be used elsewhere you have to actually call the function. For instance:

```
def print_last_line(filename):
    print getLastFile(filename)
```

Additionally there's the problem of scope, where you must define anything you want to use within the function in the function itself. For instance:

```
test = []
def use_last_line(filename):
    test.append(getLastFile(filename))  # This will error, because test is not in scope

def use_last_line(filename):
    test = []
    test.append(getLastFile(filename))  # This will success because test is in the function.
```

Specifically to do this for what I'm guessing you're trying to do above, you would want to just actually call the function and assign the result to your `hello` array:

```
hello = getLastFile(filename)
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is exactly what I need.  I'm getting an error now that csv.reader has no attribute "seek."  It was working a minute ago.  I think I'll have to start a new question if I can't work it out.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

you could open the CSV file as an array with numpy's [genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) and then slice the last row, or if you know the length of your file, it looks like 1024 in your example, you can use the skip_header keyword. i.e.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=",",skip_header=1024)
```